# Connect nestjs to redis using Docker Compose

Tags: docker, redis, nestjs

I am trying to connect my Nestjs application to Redis as follows:

This the content of my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  main:
    container_name: main
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:${PORT}
      - 9229:9229
    command: yarn start:dev
    env_file:
      - .env

    networks:
      - webnet
  redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'

networks:
  webnet:
```

In order to boostrap `redis` functionality in my nestjs application, I am using `nestjs-redis` and the relevant portion of `app.module.ts` looks like this:

```js
import { RedisModule } from 'nestjs-redis';

@Module({
 imports: [
  RedisModule.register({})
 ]
})
```

However, when I try to run `docker-compose up` in my setup, I get the following error:

`[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379`

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using `docker-compose.yml`, try to use the internal `links` capability.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  main:
    container_name: main
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:${PORT}
      - 9229:9229
    command: yarn start:dev
    links:
      - redis
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - webnet
  redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    networks:
      - webnet

networks:
  webnet:
```

and in your snippet, pass the host in the following manner

```
import { RedisModule } from 'nestjs-redis';

@Module({
 imports: [
  RedisModule.register({host: "redis"})
 ]
})
```

Comment: I've done the changes you outlined, the error message changes to `[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis`, however, if I set the host to localhost in `app.module.ts`, it goes back to the original error message.

Comment: Just added the network in `redis` section as well and can you try now?